# Select one column from output with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite, sql-server-2008

please look at the below query,

```
select column1, count(coulmn2) from table1

minus

select column1, count(coulmn2) from table2
```

In the output, i get two columns i.e `column1` and `count(column2)` after `minus` operation.

I want the query to display only `column1` in the output and not `count(column2)` but I want it to do the minus operation with both the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your query like this

```
select  column1 from 
(
  select column1, count(coulmn2) from table1

  minus

  select column1, count(coulmn2) from table2
)t
```

Essentially what we are doing is enclosing the previous output from `minus` into an inner query and doing a `Select column1` over this nested query with no affect on performance.

Comment: @CommercialSupervisor Since my solution worked for you, please mark it as answer and/or upvote the answer so that future seekers of similar problems do not face difficulty in searching right answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column1 FROM
(
  SELECT column1, COUNT(coulmn2) FROM table1

  MINUS

  SELECT column1, COUNT(coulmn2) FROM table2
)a
```